# C++: Reshape vector to 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reshape

Edit: I have uploaded the vector to Drive as a text file, in case anyone want to have a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wsPU8YebRQbDUwNFYza3ljSnc/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to reshape my vector `h` into a 3D array. `h` contains 295788 elements. In this case `height = 314`, `width = 314` and `depth = 3`. 
Basically what I'm trying to do is what MATLAB does with its reshape function.

```
h = reshape(h, height, width, depth)
```

This is my attempt so far, but when I print it all I see is zeroes, which is not right. I have double checked that `h` contains the numbers I'm expecting.

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > array3D;

int height = 314, width = 314, depth = 3;
// Set up sizes
array3D.resize(height);
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    array3D[i].resize(width);

    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        array3D[i][j].resize(depth);
}

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    array3D[i][0][0] = h[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        array3D[i][j][0] = h[i+j];
        for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
        {
            array3D[i][j][k] = h[i+j+k];
        }
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
for (vector<vector<vector<double>>>::const_iterator i = array3D.begin(); i != array3D.end(); ++i)
{
    for (vector<vector<double>>::const_iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
    {
        for (vector<double>::const_iterator k = j->begin(); k != j->end(); ++k)
        {
            cout << *k << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I convert my vector into a 3D array properly?

Comment: [`Eigen::Map<MatrixType>`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html)

Comment: Okay, I have included Eigen in my project now. But how would this work in my case then?

Comment: Am I right in that Eigen doesn't support 3D matrices?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Use [`Eigen::TensorMap`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/classEigen_1_1TensorMap.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, Henri. I edited the OP with my solution. I couldn't figure out how to use `TensorMap` but I did use `Tensor`. If you have any comments/recommendations/critique on the code I would be very happy to hear it. I'm sure there's a much better solution, but this is all I could come up with.

Comment: You could simply use `Eigen::Tensor.reshape`.  It is not documented in Doxygen, but there is an example in the [testsuite](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/2b969e50885e26f0ca909ebb2b0263cd9c649bd6/unsupported/test/cxx11_tensor_morphing.cpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: Wow. That was easy all of a sudden. Added the second solution to the OP.  Thank you again, Henri. I can't give you any sort of credit, can I? (Since you posted comments not "Answers").

Comment: @asdfghjkl may I suggest you post your solution as an **answer** if your problem is already solved. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question) with regard to adding [SOLVED] to the question title. It would be to your advantage to do so as you may score future rep points on the answer.

Comment: I don't think I deserve any credit.  After all you solved the problem yourself.  I merely gave some useful hints.

Comment: Cool, I did that. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by using Eigen::Tensor as suggested by Henri Menke. I ended up creating an array for the initial 314x314x3 matrix, and then another one for the 300x300x3 matrix. It's neither fast nor pretty, but for now that is what I could come up with. Looks like this.

For clarification: `margin` is calculated further up in the code, but in this example with the 314x314x3 matrix it's `margin=7`. `h` is a vector with 295788 elements. `nrh=314`, `nch=314` and `nradii=3`.

```
Tensor<int, 3> t(nrh, nch, nradii);
int counter = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < nradii; k++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < nch; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < nrh; row++) 
        {
            t(row, col, k) = h[counter];
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}

int height = nrh - margin * 2;
int width = nch - margin * 2;
int depth = nradii;
Tensor<int, 3> out(height, width, depth);
int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
{
    for (int j = margin; j < nch - margin; j++)
    {
        for (int i = margin; i < nrh - margin; i++)
        {
            out(count1, count2, count3) = t(i, j, k);
            count1 += 1;
        }
        count1 = 0;
        count2 += 1;
    }
    count2 = 0;
    count3 += 1;
}
```

Edit: Solution #2 with Tensor.slice()

```
int height = nrh - margin * 2;
int width = nch - margin * 2;
int depth = nradii;
Tensor<int, 3> tensor(height, width, depth);
DSizes<ptrdiff_t, 3> indices(margin, margin, 0);
DSizes<ptrdiff_t, 3> sizes(height, width, nradii);
tensor = t.slice(indices, sizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
array3D[i][j][k] = h[i*(depth*width)+j*depth+k];
```

That may or may not be scanning the vector in the correct order.

Notice how when the index `k` resets the index `j` increments so you move on exactly one until the index `j` resets in which case `i` increments and the same. It's easy to show this calculation reads every element exactly once.

I'd normally expect a `width`, `height` then `depth` and you're scanning in the opposite order!

**Footnote:** Depending on the application is may be worthwhile to just access the vector using this approach. In general it turns out to be faster than accessing a vector of vectors of vectors. That can be relevant when dealing with massive arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your the structure of your code is already ok, however, there are two mistakes:

- The lines

  ```
  array3D[i][0][0] = h[i];
  ```

  and

  ```
  array3D[i][j][0] = h[i+j];
  ```

  are pointless. You are overwriting those entries later on with the line

  ```
  array3D[i][j][k] = h[i+j+k];
  ```
- The index calculation for `h[]` is wrong: You must multiply the row index by the length of a row before adding the cell index. The assignment should look like this:

  ```
  array3D[i][j][k] = h[(i*width+j)*depth+k];
  ```

  Otherwise, you will get the same result for `(i, j, k) == (3, 2, 1)` as for `(i, j, k) == (1, 3, 2)`, which is obviously wrong. In the index calculation above, I have assumed that `k` is the fastest changing dimension. If that is not the order in which your data is stored in `h`, you need to change the positions of `i`, `j`, and `k` and adjust the factors accordingly.

Putting this together, your assignment loop should read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++) {
            array3D[i][j][k] = h[(i*width+j)*depth+k];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Slightly off-topic:
If you were using C instead of C++, you could "simply" do this:

```
size_t dataSize;
//Create a real 3D array with the dimensions (height, width, depth).
double (*array3D)[width][depth] = malloc(dataSize = height*sizeof(*array3D));
//Copy over the data from the file.
memcpy(array3D, h, dataSize);


//Print the array contents:
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++) {
            printf("%d ", array3D[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

This uses a real 3D array instead of an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of doubles (which is roughly what a `vector<vector<vector<double>>>` is). However, this cannot be done in C++ as C++ does not allow for array types with dynamic sizes as C does.